# Equipping topological manifolds with differential/complex structure

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, riemann-surfaces

Suppose a two dimensional topological manifold is given. Can it always be equipped with a differential structure (or even complex structure)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the first is positive, this was proven by Rado around 1920. For the second you need to assume that the manifold is orientable since every complex manifold is. Then your surface also admits a complex structure. One way to see this is to equip the surface with a Riemannian metric (every smooth manifold has such) and then use Gauss' theorem on isothermal coordinates to define a holomorphic atlas.